# HierarchicalDataTemplate is not applied while binding to collection consisted of ContentControls

Tags: wpf, binding, treeview, wpf-controls, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I`m binding a treeview to a collection wich items are of type ContentControl.
My hierarchical data template (and also styles) are not applied to the items.

```cs
<TreeView Name="tvCategories" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
<TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type EmailClient:EmailFolder}" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Stretch="Fill" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Source.PixelWidth}" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Source.PixelHeight}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

DataTemplate itself is correct - if I use it as a Treeview.ItemTemplate, than everything is ok. If my items are not descendants of ContentControl than everything is ok again.

Why is this happening?

Comment: strange behavior, try maybe binding an 'Items' property that is of type IEnumerable<Object> instead of IEnumerable<EmailFolder>

Comment: @jimmyjambles the Items property is of type ItemCollection (it is an IEnumerable read only collection - Items property of the ItemsControl descendant class). So Items[0], for example, will return an Object.

Comment: I only suggested it because I had that problem once, what I am suggesting just to be clear is that whatever IEnumerable you are using, you re-write a second accessor for the collection, except before you return it you convert it to a collection of Objects, not EmailFolder.  I also know it shouldn't make a difference but this worked for me once in your situation

Comment: You can also try encapsulating your ContentControl derived class with a proper ViewModel and access it in your bindings like VM.ContentControl.Title

Comment: @jimmyjambles Thank you for your suggestions! I`ve tried to use different types fore the items collection, but it doesn`t help.
I`ve changed the architecture so that the items now are not descendants of the ContentControl class (just pure data objects). Though it is not the answer to the question, of course.